# How to give variable as command parameter in double quotes?

Tags: bash, sh

I need to execute a command, which takes a parameter, needs to be in double quotes:

```
cmd --key1 --key2 "some parameter in \"double\" quotes and with {brackets}"
```

this works good from terminal, but when i use .sh script:
mess.txt: `some parameter in \"double\" quotes and with {brackets}`

nither this

```
message=$(cat mess.txt)
cmd --key1 --key2 "$message"
```

nor this

```
message=$(cat mess.txt)
cmd --key1 --key2 \"$message\"
```

and nor this

```
message=$(cat mess.txt)
cmd --key1 --key2 "\"$message\""
```

works, but
executing result of this in terminal works:

```
message=$(cat mess.txt)
echo "cmd --key1 --key2 \"$message\""
```

Any ideas, how to execute this from script?

**Update**: if i put " into file and use just $message, this does not work too.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample input and output form the script?

Comment: What shell do you use? `sh` or `bash`? Does your terminal use the same shell?

Comment: Why do you escape the double-quotes when writing it to the file ? You need not do that. Only reason why you escaped that in the original command was because you already had double-quotes outside. (You could have used single quotes, BTW)

Comment: @Thrustmaster I copied this input from terminal test to file and have not think about it! with not escaped quotes in file all works good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Converting my comment to answer]

Why do you escape the double-quotes when writing it to the file ? You need not do that. Only reason why you escaped that in the original command was because you already had double-quotes outside.

In my terminal:

```
➜  Temp  cat temp.txt
some parametr in "double" quotes and with {brackets}
➜  Temp  cat temp.py
import sys

print "\n".join(sys.argv)
➜  Temp  python temp.py "$(cat temp.txt)"
temp.py
some parametr in "double" quotes and with {brackets}
```

---

Further, in your original command, you could have used single quotes to do away with double-quotes escaping.

```
➜  Temp  python temp.py 'some parametr in "double" quotes and with {brackets}'
temp.py
some parametr in "double" quotes and with {brackets}
```